# How do I deal with a passed parameter that may have an apostrophe in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, string-formatting, jscript, testcomplete, ssms-2016

I'm using a query within a loop in TestComplete, and each time the loop completes, the variable is updated with a new value. I want to account for the possibility of an apostrophe in the variable so I can use one query. For example:

```
i = 0;

while(i < companyCount)
{                             
    result = CompanyAddress(company);
    Log.Message(result);
    i++;
}
```

'CompanyAddress' is the query I have stored in another script file, and 'company' is the variable being passed.

```
SELECT address FROM table WHERE name = '" + company + "';
```

I tried REPLACE(), but that didn't fix the problem when it got to the second iteration.

Comment: You deal with them by using parameters in your queries.

Comment: And `name = "Try this"` isn't' valid SQL Server TSQL code

Comment: Sorry for the poor example. The 'name' was meant to be a string variable passed from TestComplete into the query.

Comment: I updated the example to better replicate what I want to do.

Comment: To properly quote a string TestComplete has the `Quote()` method and SQL Server has the QUOTENAME() function. Both can be used to help build a query string. They add the outer quotes and any inner quotes required to escape a quote in the string passed.

Comment: Do not concatenate values into a query, use a proper query with parameters.

Answer (score -1):

To escape apostrophe inside a SQL string you use double apostrophe:

```
SET @name = "Dan''s example"
```

But the best way is to parametrize the query, which also heps preventing SQL injection.

Comment: I apologize, my example was poorly written. I have parameterized queries, but some of the parameters may have apostrophes. The 'name' above was meant to represent a TestComplete variable being passed into the query.

Comment: @Dan I think you should have added the code calling TestComplete. It looks like that is the place where you need to fix things. And if you are not calling from SQL Server, maybe add a tag with the programming language you are using, so people expert on that language can help you.

Comment: I updated my example to better replicate what I want to do.

Comment: The correct solution is not to try and escape the value, but to use proper parameterized queries.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Sure, that’s also what the last sentence of the answer says, isn’t?

Answer (score -2):

I incorrectly used the REPLACE() method I mentioned in my initial explanation.

I sent the variable with the single quote to the query:

```
var test = "agwh'waf'2";
```

but when I included it in the query, I used the following:

```
"select * from table where name = " + test.replace(/'/g, "\'\'");
```

This replaced single quotes in my variable with two single quotes before the query was run.

Comment: The correct solution is not to try and escape the value, but to use proper parameterized queries.